# Wrap selected points with a shape

Tags: three.js

I have a 3D scatter plot. In this plot, I can select multiple points using a 2D polygon. I want to create a shape that will wrap all the selected points inside it.
I found `ExtrudeGeometry` pretty easy to implement as the wrapper shape, but I find it confusing to place correctly.

How I select points:

1. Create a polygon: `[x,y][]` when x=offsetX and y=offsetY
2. Normalize the polygon to `devicePixelRatio`
3. Loop through all the scatter plot points
4. Project the point to the camera `vector3.project(this.camera)`
5. Convert the point to offset units: `const x = ((screenVector.x + 1) * canvasWidth) / 2;`, `const y = (-(screenVector.y - 1) * canvasHeight) / 2;`
6. Check if the offset point is inside the polygon

How I try to create the shape:

```js
// I have a list of all the `z` values of all the selected, projected to camera points, called `Zs`
// Depth should be the diff between the min and max `z`, right?
const depth = Math.max(...Zs) - Math.min(...Zs)

// For each polygon point, because their values are offsetX and offsetY, I normalize them to behave as scatter plot point
const convert = (pt: [number, number]) => {
  const x = 2*(pt[0]/canvasWidth)-1
  const y = -2*(pt[1]/canvasHeight)+1
  return [x, y]
}

const shape = new THREE.Shape();
// Draw the shape
const first = convert(normalizedPolygon.shift()!)
shape.moveTo(first[0], first[1])
normalizedPolygon.forEach(pt => {
  const point = convert(pt)
  shape.lineTo(point[0],point[1])
})
shape.lineTo(first[0], first[1])

const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, {
  steps: 2,
  depth,
  bevelEnabled: false,
} );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, transparent: true, opacity: 0.1, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) ;
// Make the shape face the camera?
mesh.lookAt( this.camera.position );
this.scene.add( mesh );
```

And this is what I get: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8b6HKAqIYE

As you can see, there's a bit difference between what I want and what I have.
I'd love to get some help :)

Comment: Have you considered using a convex hull?

Comment: @PhilN. yes. Unfortunatelly it contains inside its area dots that were not selected using the polygon.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. The YT video seems to show the proper points being selected (turn red) when they're inside your lasso shape. What is the issue you're encountering?

Comment: @Marquizzo you're right. the youtube example is a bit confusing. It's not the selection of the points which concerns me, but the 3D polygon I try to draw

Comment: Are you sure your normalization is correct? You can try to debug the values of the shape that you create.